# Code Contracts + Async in .NET 4.5: "The method or operation is not implemented"

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, code-contracts, async-await, c#-5.0

I receive the following compilation error from ccrewrite when using Code Contracts 1.4.51019.0 in VS2012 on Windows 7 x64: "The method or operation is not implemented."

It appears to be caused by a combination of property accessors and the use of `async` methods which lack an inner `await`.

**Reproduction steps:**

Create a new class library with 'Full' Runtime Contract Checking enabled:

```
namespace CodeContractsAsyncBug
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Service
    {
        // Offending method!
        public async Task ProcessAsync(Entity entity)
        {
            var flag = entity.Flag;
        }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Removing the 'async' modifier fixes the issue, I presume?

Comment: Yes (except you would then need to return a Task).

Comment: This is Mike Barnett's project.  He likes getting email so don't hesitate to ping him about this bug.  mbarnett _at_ microsoft _dot_ com

Comment: Have raised this here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/codecontracts/thread/bdb88f77-469a-40c7-ace6-2c1840fb1a8e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in version 1.5 of Code Contracts.

Answer (score 2):

An `async` method that does not `await` is usually indicative of a programming error. There is a compiler warning that will inform you of this situation.

If you wish to synchronously implement a method with an asynchronous signature, the normal way to do this is to implement a non-`async` method and return a `Task`, such as `Task.FromResult<object>(null)`. Note that with this approach, exceptions are raised synchronously instead of being placed on the returned `Task`.

Comment: I am aware of its correct use and you're right in saying that fixing up non-async code resolves the issue. It is still a Code Contracts bug, however :)

Answer (score 1):

Over the last several months, we have fixed many issues with rewriting async methods. I would suggest you try your code again on the latest installer and if you are still having a problem, please provide a complete repro.

Answer (score 0):

I believe async keyword just stands for that - either you have a await during the code, by which it will be generated a Task and handled when the method is called, or you need to return a Task explicitly.

Comment: You certainly *can* have `async` method without `await`. It usually means that the author of the code doesn't understand how `async` works (and it produces a warning because of that), but it does work and I think it can be useful in some rare cases.

Comment: There are some other subtle differences too. For example, an exception thrown from an async method will always be applied to the task, and never raise synchronously.